# Get MultipartFile amount of uploaded files

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I have a method that processes the POST request for files using MultipartFile.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/payment-files", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE) 
public PaymentFileStatus postPaymentFile(
         @RequestParam("paymentFile") MultipartFile file,
) {
    byte[] fileBytes;
    try {
        fileBytes = file.getBytes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new PublicException(MESSAGE_NOT_READABLE, e);
    }

    return foo(fileBytes);
}
```

My task is to reject the request if more than one file is uploaded. I was wondering if I somehow can get the number of uploaded files from the MultipartFile object? Or do you have any other ideas how to check how many files were uploaded? Or maybe I should use `@PreAuthorize`? Or maybe the validation should be implemented in other place? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestParam("paymentFile") MultipartFile file,
```

change to
`@RequestParam("paymentFile") List<MultipartFile> file,`
After that, you can get number file you uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Pass multiple MultipartFile files in array.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/payment-files", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE) 
public PaymentFileStatus postPaymentFile(
         @RequestParam("paymentFile") MultipartFile[] file
) {
    byte[] fileBytes;
    try {
        fileBytes = file.getBytes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new PublicException(MESSAGE_NOT_READABLE, e);
    }

    return foo(fileBytes);
}
```

Refer :- [Solution](https://hellokoding.com/uploading-multiple-files-example-with-spring-boot/)